# An alternative to app engine to use drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api

I basically want to write an app that uses the Drive API. developers.google.com has tutorials on how to do that. But problem is that their example asks me to first create an app engine instance, which I don't want to, as I've heard pretty bad reviews about it. So, I just wanted to know whether there is/are any alternative/s available, and what challenges I would possibly have to face when using the service/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Drive app on any platform that can make an HTTPS request, so pretty much, any platform. When you choose one, if you have any problems, get back to us.

Also, you should probably try out App Engine before making a decision based on "reviews you read".

Comment: yeah, I actually faced a few problems myself when I first used app engine (mainly because of inexperience). I'm planning to start over and try my best to implement in app engine itself. Just asked because I wanted to know that there *is* an alternative if app engine gives a lot of trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine has a few convenience classes around Credential storage and User Id. Aside from that a standard servlet app and a GAE app are pretty much the same.